# How to use linkTextAttributes in UITextview swift

Tags: ios, swift, markdown, uitextview

I am changing the hyperlink colour when I am receiving the links from the server response. But it affects the alpha numeric also. I don't want to change the hyperlink colour for the numeric items. In my case, I am receiving the account number from the response and the text colour is changed as the hyperlink colour.

Eg :

```
   2344-323-3242
  (23432-3423-324)  
  /n 23234-324-234-234

subtitleTextView.linkTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor.rawValue: ThemeColor.textHyperLinkColor.value, NSAttributedStringKey.underlineStyle.rawValue: NSUnderlineStyle.styleNone.rawValue]
```

Comment: Perhaps you need to disable phone number detection in the UITextView

Comment: @PrzemysławWrzesiński, Can you please let me know if we have any properties for disable the phone number alone?  As I know 
about this propery  textview.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeAll;

Comment: If you are sure you want everything except the phone number: `subtitleTextView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypes(rawValue: UIDataDetectorTypes.link.rawValue + UIDataDetectorTypes.address.rawValue + UIDataDetectorTypes.calendarEvent.rawValue + UIDataDetectorTypes.shipmentTrackingNumber.rawValue + UIDataDetectorTypes.flightNumber.rawValue + UIDataDetectorTypes.lookupSuggestion.rawValue)`

but consider carefully if you really need them all.

Comment: @PrzemysławWrzesiński, It's working fine. Can you please post this in answer section. , Thksan

Comment: Happy to hear that @Devan, I've posted it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to just disable the phone number detection. From code you need to add all the detectors you need - if you need all detectors except the phone number the code will be:

```
subtitleTextView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypes(rawValue:
    UIDataDetectorTypes.link.rawValue +
    UIDataDetectorTypes.address.rawValue +
    UIDataDetectorTypes.calendarEvent.rawValue +
    UIDataDetectorTypes.shipmentTrackingNumber.rawValue +
    UIDataDetectorTypes.flightNumber.rawValue +
    UIDataDetectorTypes.lookupSuggestion.rawValue)
```

Comment: What about using `all` and remove the phone number one?

Comment: My personal preference would be explicitly stating what values you'd like to detect, so you won't get any surprises, but yes - it is also possible.